# Debugging PL/Python functions

Tags: debugging, postgresql, plpgsql, plsqldeveloper, plperl

I just practiced some happy engineering and wrote lots of code without testing each step as I usually do.

So now I have a few hundred lines of code with an error somewhere... I am using pgAdmin III to write the Python and I write it in their Query Tool, which is used for normal SQL queries. I will not past my Python code as I do not want help with this specific problem. Instead I am after a tool, which will provide me with the exact position in a PL/Python function where the error occurred. To see my reason for wanting this, the following is the error message I am getting, and I have way of debugging where the error occured:

```
********** Error **********

ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "atextstring"
SQL state: 22P02
```

Comment: I believe there is some work on getting tracebacks to work for pl/python, checkout this thread http://marc.info/?l=pgsql-hackers&m=129311253822050&w=2 Although that might not help you *now*, unless you are willing to do some work :-)

Comment: @plundra. I believe this answers my question, as it proves that it does not already exist (or at least not for ordinary people like me).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been using PL/pgSQL for a while and I haven't found a debbuging tool.